# bash: replace in a string './' for newline

Tags: string, bash, replace, find, newline

after using find I need to iterate the files

```
var=`find -name "reg"`
#replace ./ for newline
for file in $var; do 
    #something
done
```

edit: SOLVED with ${string#*/} it takes away the ./
I can survive with that I think

Comment: Much easier: `find -name "reg" -exec <your code> \;`. Within "your code", you refer to the current findee as `{}`. Even better is to use `find -name "reg" -print | xargs <your command>`, if your command supports that style.

Comment: (1.) `-execdir` is safer than `-exec`.  (2.) `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ... ` is safer than `-print ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### EDIT:

I am not concerned about how you get the $file, using command line or whatever suits you. I am much more concerned about the `#do something` part of your question, which I believe is the main question and all those who are posting various `find -name 'reg' | xargs ...` should think twice before complicating the matters for OP.

---

use sed

```
var=`find -name "reg"`
#replace ./ for newline
for file in $var; do 
    sed -i 's|\./|\n|g' $file
done
```

remove the -i options to get output on the screen, if satisfied output is obtained use -i to actually change the line.
On second read, maybe I am replacing the other way round, perhaps you want to replace newline with ./ ? Its bit complicated

```
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s|\n|./|g' $file
```

as always, test without -i option and then decide if you want to modify the file.
For explanation of second sed magic, read [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n/1252191#1252191) . Its exactly same, except for the `./` character for replace string.

Comment: thanks I solved it with ${string#*/} I'll try to survive with this

Answer (score 0):

```
find -name "reg" | while read file; do ...; done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  var="${line#./}"
  echo "$var"
done < <(find . -name reg -print)
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I finally solved it guys, i could delete the ./
string=./blabla/bla

string=${string#*/} #delete stuff until the first / included

echo $string #got blabla/bla

Comment: and what if your string contains `blah./blabla/bla` ? you will lose the first 'blah.' , and it removes the substring, NOT replace it, I think you did NOT explained your question properly

Comment: it will never start with something before ./   find returns ./some/file   ./some/other/file